# Is this statement true about PDF files?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

PDF files are not editable. Using Adobe tools a limited degree of editing can be done, but not in the general sense - PDF is not a word processing file format. Some modifications are possible -watermarking, digital signing, extraction of text, removing or adding of pages-, but editing - no

Comment: You could simply give it a try by yourself?!?

Comment: If you can edit the contents of the generated PDF (you have write permissions), then of course, as long as the editing program accepts it (no errors).

Comment: Adobe tools are paid. I don't have the software. And also i've found this statement:  "PDF files are not editable. Using Adobe tools a limited degree of editing can be done, but not in the general sense - PDF is not a word processing file format. Some modifications are possible -watermarking, digital signing, extraction of text, removing or adding of pages-, but editing - no"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like something I wrote:

> PDF files are not editable. Using Adobe tools a limited degree of
>   editing can be done, but not in the general sense - PDF is not a word
>   processing file format. Some modifications are possible -watermarking,
>   digital signing, extraction of text, removing or adding of pages-, but
>   editing - no.

This was true when I wrote it. Acrobat 9 didn't allow editing. Acrobat XI is somewhat more evolved.

**Assumption:**
You've created a PDF with iTextSharp. If you've seen [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZnbhnU4m3Y), you may have tagged the PDF, but as not that many people know this option to create Tagged PDFs using iText(Sharp), let's assume that you've created an ordinary PDF, also excluding interactive PDFs (AcroForm or XFA).

Such PDFs can be "redacted" using Acrobat XI as described on Adobe's site: http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/pdf-redaction.html

Such files can also be "edited" using Acrobat XI although the editing functionality is limited: http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/editing-pdf-documents.html

PDF is not an editing format, but Adobe has continuously improved Acrobat to allow people to manually change content on a page. Doing the edits by code is much less trivial (and most of the times impossible).

I don't know the background of your question, but suppose that you wanted to *protect* your document against editing, then you'd want to *digitally sign* the document. In that case, editing the document would break the signature: people would immediately see that the document has been tampered with, because the signature panel would show a red cross instead of a blue ribbon (certification signature) or a green check mark (approval signature).

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I am basically creating a simple PDF file with iTextSharp which has some paragraphs with text, i was asked if this file could be editable (if the already generated text can be changed.)

Answer (score 1):

Portable Document Format (PDF) is a file format used to present documents in a manner independent of application software, hardware, and operating systems. Each PDF file encapsulates a complete description of a fixed-layout flat document, including the text, fonts, graphics, and other information needed to display it. In 1991, Adobe Systems co-founder John Warnock outlined a system called "Camelot" that evolved into PDF.

There is specialized software for editing PDF files, though the choices are much more limited and often more expensive than creating and editing standard editable document formats. Version 0.46 and later of Inkscape allows PDF editing through an intermediate translation step involving Poppler.